# Why does Edit Mode show a different number of vertices than Object Mode?

Tags: vertices

When I look at my object in Object Mode it says 110k vertices. The problem is, when I select my model it says 13k vertices. I have no clue where the extra vertices are, or how to delete them. I'm trying to use UMA (for unity) and I need to have less than 65k vertices in total.

I have no clue as to where to find the missing vertices.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The object level vertex count includes vertices generated by modifiers. In this case it's probably your subdivision surface modifier.

Answer (score 2):

When you are in object mode, Blender counts all the objects in the scene's vertices.

Blender also counts modifiers in object mode. For example, the subdivision surface modifier would make the object mode vertex count higher than the edit mode vertex count.